# headerFilterParams function throws "cell is undefined" error

Tags: tabulator

See: http://jsfiddle.net/wc8mqf0t/1

```
function columnHeaderMenu() {
    return [{
        label: "Clear Filter",
        action: function (e, column) {
            column.setHeaderFilterValue("");
        }
    }]
}

function editorParams(cell) {
    let table = this;
    let valuesObj = {
        multiselect: true,
        sortValuesList: "asc",
        values: table.getData("active").map(data => data[cell.getField()])
        //values: true
    };

    return valuesObj;
}

let table = new Tabulator("#table", {
    data: [
        { "col1": "a" },
        { "col1": "b" },
        { "col1": "c" }
    ],
    columns: [
        {
            title: "Column1",
            field: "col1",
            headerMenu: columnHeaderMenu,
            headerFilter: "select",
            headerFilterParams: editorParams,
            headerFilterFunc: "in",
            headerFilterLiveFilter: false
        }
    ]
});
```

In my tabulator table, I have a custom headerFilterParams function that should populate the filter with only the "active" values in the table.

However, when the filter is open nothing is initially populated, and then upon calling my clear filter function, a "cell is undefined" error is thrown, despite the documentation showing that the cell is an available argument for editors.

In the JSFiddle, if you comment out the "values" property in editorParams and switch it to true, it works fine, however this is not the desired results, I only want the values that are visible or "active" as the documentation call it

I appreciate any help with this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to an error in the documentation, the cell is never passed into that function, I would suggest [Razing a Bug on the Repo](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Possible+Bug&template=bug_report.md&title=) and they can get a fix out for that in the next week or so